# React Router Error Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: java, reactjs, react-router-dom

I make react router app. But I have an error. I can not identify it. I am new react developer.

My app code is:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter className='bodyMy'>
      <HeardTitle />
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Card} />
        <Route exact path="/class" component={Card2} />
      
      </Switch>
      
      
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

and my navbar code:

```
export default function navbar() {
    return (
        <Fragment className='myNavbar'>
            <ul>
                <li >
                    <NavLink activeStyle={{ color:'green', fontWeight: "bold" }} exact to="/">Function</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <NavLink  activeStyle={{ color:'red', fontWeight: "bold" }} exact to="/class">Class</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <NavLink href="#pricing">Logout</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

It shows TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Comment: I think it should be `export default function Navbar()` **capital N** since you make the component in the app.js something like this `<Navbar />`

Answer (score 1):

In navbar change

```
<NavLink href="#pricing">Logout</NavLink>
```

to

```
<NavLink to="#pricing">Logout</NavLink>
```